# How simulate click on element?

Tags: python, python-3.x, parsing

I parse a certain pag and find an element (small image) on this page. I need to simulate a click on this element; the click will open modal window which contains a large image. This large image is my target.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from mechanize import Browser

url = 'https://www.avito.ru/saransk/kvartiry/1-k_kvartira_47_m_25_et._1610295577'
headers = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/72.0.3626.96 Safari/537.36'}
browser = Browser()

page_html = requests.get(url, headers=headers).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(page_html, 'lxml')
img_obj = soup.find('div', {'class': 'gallery-imgs-container'}).find('img')  # small image
img_url = 'https:' + img_obj['src']
print(img_url)
```

But I need to simulate a click on a small image

Comment: You might want to think about using [selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/).

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used mechanize before but a quick google search after
try img_obj.submit()